# Javascript: array.indexOf() not returning correct index of elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

array:

```
values: [5,4,4,5,6,6]
```

I want to get the index of the elements. so, I am looping through it.

```
values.map((val) => {
        console.log('val', value.indexOf(val));
        console.log('val of 5', value.indexOf(5));
        console.log('val of 4', value.indexOf(4));
        console.log('val of 4', value.indexOf(4));
        console.log('val of 5', value.indexOf(5));
        console.log('val of 6', value.indexOf(6));
        console.log('val of 6', value.indexOf(6));
        return value.indexOf(val);
      });
```

`expected output` `0,1,2,3,4`

current output

```
0
1
1
0
4
4
```

where I am going wrong?

Comment: `indexOf` returns the index of the _first_ occurrence of the item, if you want the index of the current item, you can use the index argument passed into `.map((elem, idx) => ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const values = [5,4,4,5,6,6]
const indexes = values.map((val, idx) => {
        console.log(`Index of ${val} is ${idx}`);
        return idx;
});
```